# Kivy: Unknown class <WindowManager> Error on simple "Hello World" script?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I was working on different kivy tutorials, all was working well. Then today, I started having an error when running a script that was previously working:

```
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <WindowManager>
```

I tried fiddling around, had no clue what was wrong. Then I tried to run a simple Hello World script:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello world')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And I still get the exception. Here is what it returns:

```
   File "C:\Users\Manu\Dropbox\Python\other\Test.py", line 14, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "D:\Progs\Pyton37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 828, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "D:\Progs\Pyton37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 599, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "D:\Progs\Pyton37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "D:\Progs\Pyton37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 399, in load_string
     widget = Factory.get(parser.root.name)(__no_builder=True)
   File "D:\Progs\Pyton37\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 131, in __getattr__
     raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <WindowManager>
```

So this is strange, since everything was working well this morning, and I did not install other packages or modules.

I tried pip uninstall kivy, and pip install kivy to get a clean install. Tried rebooting. No luck. And the error is both on PyScripter and PyCharm.

I have no clue what's going on here...
Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any file with extension .kv in folder "C:\Users\Manu\Dropbox\Python\other\"?

Comment: @eyllansec : Ok so I removed the 4 *.kv files I had in the folder, and that solved the issue. That's great, thanks!Was going to ask why that would cause a conflict, but just realised that in one of them (my.kv) it referenced classes from a previous tutorial, so each time the myApp class was called, it would crash... Anyhow, thanks heaps :)

Comment: I recommend you create a folder for each project, tutorial, etc. to isolate the problems, other recommendations is that you use a venv, etc.

Comment: Kivy by default tries to load `x.kv` if the name of the class that inherits from App is `Xapp`

Comment: @eyllanesc: Ok did not know that, regarding kivy trying to load by default the same prefix. Will definitely start using folders now :)

Comment: read the docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv

Comment: For not having this problem I use `Builder.load_file('file.kv')` and I make sure that I name the kv file so it does not autoload. As I rule I use `main.py` and `main.kv` for the main entry point and then  `mycustom.py`, `mycustom.kv`, for subsequent files.